# Save another sheet as pdf while loop through a dropdown, without showing 'save as' box for each item

Tags: excel, vba

I have this dropdown menu on Sheet 9, and I need the macro to loop through all items in the dropdown in cell E5 and save a copy of Sheet10 as pdf with each different information referenced by the item in the dropdown list. I did not want to have to save as each document, so it would be good to have a code that could save all of the documents in an specific folder with different names according to what is writen in cell E5. (this process will happen every month, so it would be good if it could save all documents in a different folder each month). So far I have a code that just saves sheet 10, but I couldnt figure out the loop yet. Does anyone have a code that would do that? :)

Comment: Your Sheet 9 cell E5 dropdown - where is the data source for that dropdown? Ideally, you want that to be a range.You need to write some VBA that reads each cell of that source range and loads it into E5. You wrap that whole loop around your existing save-as-a-pdf code but insert the value loaded to E5 into the filename it saves as. Have a go at this and if you hit issues - post what you've got for us to look at/comment on.

Comment: E5 is getting info from another Sheet, so everytime this other sheet is updated, the dropdown is also updated.

Comment: So your loop needs to start with something like `For Each DropdownItem in Otherworkbook.Sheets("OtherWorksheetname").Range("RangeofDropdown").text`

Comment: Thank you very much.. It is just saving one pdf, as it was doing before.  (VBA is kinda new for me, so im struggling a bit.. sorry)

Comment: For clarity - the E5 dropdown list has several items.  You want to go through all the items in that drop down list and then - this is where I get lost.  Are you putting data on sheet10 that comes from each member of the dropdown list, and then saving sheet10 as a .pdf just for that data, then you erase sheet10 and get data from the second element of the dropdown, and then want to save that as a separate pdf, and on and on until you have created separate pdf's for all items in the dropdown list?  And it seems like you are using sheet10 over and over again as the sheet to save as a pdf, right?

Comment: So, Sheet 10 is a template and is filled by information indicated in sheet 9, cell E5. Every time a different item in the dropdown E5 is selected, Sheet 10 changes. I want the code to select each item o the dropdown and save sheet 10 template filled in with the respective info indicated by what was selected in E5.. But i dont want to have to 'save as' each document. Id prefer that just pressing the button in sheet 9, all the loop and pdf generation was automatically saved in a specific folder. and yes, I am using sheet 10 over and over again as the pdf template.

Comment: *"So far I have a code that just saves sheet 10"* Show us this code in your question! It's usually so much easier for us to adapt your code than write from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think when E5 is changed it automatically changes data on Sheet10, and so sheet1o will be different for each item selected in Sheet1.range("E5") drop down.  If so, then this will work.  If not, it will at least show you how to create a new folder for the current month and save your sheet10 as pdf files to that folder.

```
    Sub testDir()

    Dim mnth As String
    Dim yr As String
    Dim dateString As String
    Dim pathToDir As String
    Dim myFolder As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim totalElements
    Dim element As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim activeSh As Worksheet
    Dim aWB As Worksheet


    Set activeSh = Sheets("Sheet9")
    activeSh.Activate
    Set aWB = Sheets("Sheet10")

    '   set up folder and path for current month
    pathToDir = "C:\Temp\"
    mnth = Left(MonthName(Month(Date)), 3)
    yr = Year(Date)
    dateString = yr & "_" & mnth
    myFolder = pathToDir & dateString

    If Not ifFolderExists(myFolder) Then
        ' Folder for current month does not exist yet
        ' Create folder "C:\Temp\2017_Feb" or whatever current year and month is
        Beep
        MkDir myFolder
    End If

    '   Get  items from dropdown list
    Set totalElements = Evaluate(Range("E5").Validation.Formula1)

    '   This is where I'm fuzzy -
    '   If when you select each item, does that automatically change data on Sheet10?
    '   If so, do this

    For Each element In totalElements
       if element.name <> "" then            
        Sheet1.Range("E5").Value = element
        myFile = myFolder & "\" & "_" & element & ".pdf"
        ChDir myFolder
        aWB.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            myFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
            False
       End if
    Next element

    End Sub


Public Function ifFolderExists(folderPath As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    ifFolderExists = (GetAttr(folderPath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: I put the sheet1 instead of sheet9.  Sorry, I didn't see that.  I'll change the script in the answer.  Try it now.

Comment: Hi again :) The macro is working perfectly, but it is creating an empty pdf template on the folder, because the dropdown E5 gets data from another sheet that is gradually updated, therefore some items in the dropdown E5 are empty. So the macro interprets this 0 as a value and generates an empty pdf template. Do you know how could I do "just generate pdf if E5 is not empty/0"? Thank you so much again!!

Comment: Probably due to the fact that there is an empty element in your dropdown.  Try using something like "If element.name <> "" then" statement.  I adjusted the code above.